# [[.default`(object, name, exact = TRUE) : subscript out of bounds exception. in Update() - R

Tags: r, knn

I am trying to build a KNN model in r. I am aware of load/save/update functions to reuse an existing saved .rda model. However, when i load the knn model and try update the model , i get an Error in update() `[[.default`(object, name, exact = TRUE) : subscript out of bounds exception.

```
load("knn.rda")
m11 <- update( m1, data =train_n )
```

Comment: Did you load `library(class)`?

Comment: Pleas edit the title making it more informative about the error your met.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Edited the title

Comment: I figured to update the knn model. Thank you!